# Invalid redirect_uri even though they are the same

Tags: identityserver4

When trying to login to identityserver (using .net core 3 preview) I get Invalid redirect_uri error even though the request uri and the allowed one are identical.

What else could I be doing wrong?

```cs
fail: IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator[0]
      Invalid redirect_uri: http://localhost:1337/authentication/login-callback
{
        "ClientId": "myapp",
        "ClientName": "myapp",
        "AllowedRedirectUris": [
          "http://localhost:1337/authentication/login-callback"
        ],
        "SubjectId": "anonymous",
        "RequestedScopes": "",
        "Raw": {
          "client_id": "myapp",
          "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:1337/authentication/login-callback",
          "response_type": "id_token token",
          "scope": "webAPI openid profile",
          "state": "5a10fc5a7006475c8d3a348c711ca58a",
          "nonce": "ae6f9f35837241e1ba3841c2ff8a4fce",
          "prompt": "none"
        }
      }
fail: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint[0]
      Request validation failed
```

Comment: can you let us know what is the complete url that you are using, (connect/authorize)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong profile in the new identity server features in core 3. Was using "IdentitySpa" - should have been "SPA"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-3.0#other-configuration-options

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add for whoever needs a more in depth explanation that the reason this doesn't work for `IdentityServerSPA` client types is the fact that when you call `AddApiAuthorization` thus:

```cs
            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();
```

The library code runs this from the file [IdentityServerBuilderConfigurationExtensions.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/26b9e60dc66f3a9a4fd5caa1578ec419ee97347b/src/Identity/ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer/src/IdentityServerBuilderConfigurationExtensions.cs#L65) line 65 does this:

```cs
builder.AddAspNetIdentity<TUser>()
    .AddOperationalStore<TContext>()
    .ConfigureReplacedServices()  // <-- This is the line
    .AddIdentityResources()
    .AddApiResources()
    .AddClients()
    .AddSigningCredentials();
```

And [`ConfigureReplacedServices`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/26b9e60dc66f3a9a4fd5caa1578ec419ee97347b/src/Identity/ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer/src/IdentityServerBuilderConfigurationExtensions.cs#L256) does this:

```cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IRedirectUriValidator, RelativeRedirectUriValidator>();
```

And [`RelativeRedirectUriValidator`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/26b9e60dc66f3a9a4fd5caa1578ec419ee97347b/src/Identity/ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer/src/Extensions/RelativeRedirectUriValidator.cs#L28) validates the redirect URI by first checking if the client type is `IdentityServerSPA` or not, thus:

```cs
public override Task<bool> IsRedirectUriValidAsync(string requestedUri, Client client)
{
    if (IsLocalSPA(client))
    {
        return ValidateRelativeUris(requestedUri, client.RedirectUris);
    }
    else
    {
        return base.IsRedirectUriValidAsync(requestedUri, client);
    }
}
```

When [`IsLocalSPA`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/26b9e60dc66f3a9a4fd5caa1578ec419ee97347b/src/Identity/ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer/src/Extensions/RelativeRedirectUriValidator.cs#L50) is defined thus:

```cs
private static bool IsLocalSPA(Client client) =>
    client.Properties.TryGetValue(ApplicationProfilesPropertyNames.Profile, out var clientType) &&
    ApplicationProfiles.IdentityServerSPA == clientType;
```

I add this answer both to help others, and to help myself understand this better :)

Answer (score 1):

It might not be the same issue (I am far from being and expert here). But I did have the same problem which made me find this article.

I found in my case, the problem was a missing trailing / on the return url. This github issue triggered me: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/21167. Look down a bit for a comment by JefSchraag on May 1, 2020.

This modification in the RedirectToLogin.razor component in my client project seemed to solve the problem.

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    var returnUrl = Navigation.Uri;

    if (!returnUrl.EndsWith('/'))
    {
        returnUrl += '/';
    }

    Navigation.NavigateTo($"authentication/login?returnUrl={returnUrl}");
}
```

Comment: Damn me too :| The missing  / at the end